# Using jq to change each variable in the array seperatly

Tags: jq

I have an array like this:

```
[
{"price": 10},
{"price": 20},
{"price": 30}
]
```

I want to go over each price item and set it to be negative.

If i do something like this:

```
.[].price = .[].price * -1
```

I'll get:

```
[
  {
    "price": -10
  },
  {
    "price": -10
  },
  {
    "price": -10
  }
]
[
  {
    "price": -20
  },
  {
    "price": -20
  },
  {
    "price": -20
  }
]
[
  {
    "price": -30
  },
  {
    "price": -30
  },
  {
    "price": -30
  }
]
```

How do i do it properly so at the end it will look like this?

```
[
{"price": -10},
{"price": -20},
{"price": -30}
]
```

Comment: Found a simple solution:

.[].price *= -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output is to be an array, then consider:

```
map( .price |= -1 * . )
```

If the price on output must be negative even if the input price is already negative, then you could replace the expression in parens by:

```
  if .price > 0 then .price |= -1 * . else . end
```

Comment: Thanks.
What if i have something more complicated?

like:

    { "prices": [{"price": 10, "random": 11},{"price": 20, "random": 22},{"price": 30, "random": 33}]}

Comment: Rest assured, it can be very easily done. A small investment of your time in learning jq using the official tutorial and manual would be well worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
.[] as $x | { price: ($x.price * -1) }
```

Here is a working example:
https://jqplay.org/s/VeGHuouLRY

Comment: Nope.
I'll will output:

    [
      -10,
      -10,
      -10
    ]
    [
      -20,
      -20,
      -20
    ]
    [
      -30,
      -30,
      -30
    ]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: The original question asks for the result to be an array. This could be done e.g. using map

Comment: This will create a new array/dict.
What if i want to keep the original array and just update the values in it?